# htaccess RewriteRule: Remove and replace

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect via .htaccess, old URL is like

`https://www.domain.de/something/?action=login&params=1`

New URL should be like:

`https://www.domain.de/something/login.php?params=1`

So, in short words:

Remove: `?action=`

Use action text as script name: `login` should be the script name `login.php`

All following parameters should be appended in unchanged way.

Any ideas for that? I guess it must be split into two rules?

I tried like that, but "something" and the action param are still added after `login.php?` and I would have to implement for each script name manually:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*action=login.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/something/login.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt?

Comment: Something like:
`code`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*action=get_logins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/something/get_logins.php?$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?action=([^&]+)(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%2.php?%1%3 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

However if you don't want full redirect (URL to change in browser) then remove `R` flag from this rule.